# div with dynamic content is not scrollable

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have 3 components. `AppointmentsPage`, `AppointmentsList`, and `AppointmentCard`. I display `N` number of `AppointmentCard`s in the `AppointmentList` component, which is rendered on `AppointmentsPage`.

The problem I'm facing is that when the cards in the list start to overflow out of the `AppointmentsList`, instead of the list becoming scrollable, each `AppointmentCard` starts resizing itself to fit inside the width of the `AppointmentsList`. Find code below. I'm using React and Tailwind.

Keep in mind that AppointmentsPage is what's rendered on the page, and that it's parent has a width of `w-9/12`.

**AppointmentsPage**

```js
export default function AppointmentsPage({clinic}) {
   return(
      <AppointmentsList appointments={clinic.appointments} />
   )
```

**AppointmentsList**

```js
export default function AppointmentList({ appointments }) {
    return(
        <div className="w-full h-auto flex flex-col font-sans">
            <div className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
                <h2 className="text-2xl text-gray-500">Incoming Appointments</h2>
                <span className="text-xl text-gray-400">5 Pending Approval</span>
            </div>

            <div className="w-full h-auto bg-black flex gap-3 overflow-x-auto">
                {appointments.map((appointment) => {
                    return <AppointmentListCard appointment={appointment} key={"appointment_" + appointment.id}/>
                })}
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**AppointmentListCard**

```js
export default function AppointmentListCard({ appointment }) {
    return(
        <div className="h-52 w-52 rounded-md bg-slate-400 p-5 flex flex-col justify-center">
            <div className="flex flex-row gap-3 ">
                <span>Patient Name: </span>
                <span className="text-gray-400">{appointment.patient?.name}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: In order to receive a specific answer you might have to provide a minimal reproducible example. It probably has to do with the fact that you have w-full , h-auto, overflow-auto. Also you have a lot of styling, and I suspect you don't need it all (even more it might even be related to your issue, because it is hard to tell for sure what will be the final outcome from just looking at so many rules for a component and it's childs)

Comment: @Berci as soon as you added this comment, I started making a JSFiddle, and realized that if I add a min-width and min-height to the `AppointmentCard`, it would fix the issue, and it did. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything stays the same, but what fixed my issue was setting a minimum width to the `AppointmentCard` component, which prevented it from resizing down. Such a silly issue lol